# How can I write each character from string to separate div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is what I have been far

**This is my code:**

```
function createWordTiles() {
            var word = ['Example'];
            var innerDiv;

            var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
            iDiv.id = 'tileBlock';
            iDiv.className = "tileBlock";
```

**Code works only i remove loop :**

```
            for (var l = 0; l <= word.length ; l++) {

                innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                innerDiv.id = 'Block' + l;
                innerDiv.className = 'Block';
                innerDiv.innerHTML = word.charAt(l);
            }

            iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
        }
```

> **This is what I have made**

How can I write each character from string to separate div using JavaScript?

Comment: Your problem is that your reassigning the value of `innerDiv` with each iteration without actually acting upon it's current value.

Comment: This way you are appending just the last innerDiv element. Try to move your `iDiv. appendChild(innerDiv) inside the loop.

Comment: Ohh Thank you sir!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);` inside the for loop, like this:

```
for (var l = 0; l <= word.length ; l++) {

    innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.id = 'Block' + l;
    innerDiv.className = 'Block';
    innerDiv.innerHTML = word.charAt(l);

    iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
}
```

Comment: And also `<=` to `<` ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ why? "less than and equal to" is valid.

Comment: <= gives you an empty div in the end.

Comment: Oh I see, with respect to the zero based index, yes you would exceed the character limit. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="source-text">Hello world</p>
</div>
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var sourceText = $('.source-text').text(); // get the source text
var $destinationElm = $('.list'); // get destination 

var i;
for(i = 0; i < sourceText.length; i++) {  // eterate through all characters
    $destinationElm.append('<li>' + sourceText[i] + '</li>'); // appends html element with text
}});
```